# Determinant of a $3 \times 3$ matrix with element sum $k$

Tags: matrices, determinant

The sum of all the elements of a $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ is $k$. What is the maximum value of the *determinant* of $A$?

Answer (score 3):

There should be no maximum value.  If we want $\det A = M^3$, then letting:
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}M & -3M+k & 0 \\ 0 & M & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & M \end{pmatrix}$$ should have the sum of all elements be $k$, and $\det A = M^3$.

Comment: Can we make it upper triangular plox?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo Isn't it currently upper triangular?

Comment: oh yeah, anyway, the determinant of upper triangular matrices is the product of the diagonal in case anyone was wondering.